# Implementing DbCommand doesn't implement all abstract class

Tags: c#, ado.net, abstract-class, implementation

I try to implement the abstract DbCommand class (like OdbcCommand, OleDbCommand, ...) but a thing that I don't understand is why when I write :

```
internal sealed class SybaseCommand : DbCommand, IDisposable
```

and I ask VS2008 to implement all the abstract class, it doesn't generate automatically all override stub for each method / property.

Here is the MSDN DbCommand class : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.common.dbcommand.aspx

It doesn't generate me the stub for the property for "Connection", "CanRaiseEvents" / ... and not the stub for ExecuteReader().

Can you tell me why? I've missed something?

Thanks for help :)

[EDIT]

In case of the ExecuteReader() method, there are 3 methods

```
public DbDataReader ExecuteReader()
public DbDataReader ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
protected abstract DbDataReader ExecuteDbDataReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
```

Can I suppose that both public methods are only calling the protected one?

Comment: I beilive it only adds stubs for abstract methods and properties.

Comment: Try using ReSharper, they usually provide you with much more options on these kind of things. http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/

Comment: According to .NET Reflector (http://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/reflector/) this is the implementation: `public DbDataReader ExecuteReader() { return this.ExecuteDbDataReader(CommandBehavior.Default); }`

Comment: Isn't simple to know this but thanks, it's very nice :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [asawyer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/426894/asawyer) said, it is only meaningful to override methods and properties that you actually *can* override, i.e. `virtual` and `abstract` members.

To "override" non-virtual or non-abstract members, you have to use the [`new` modifier](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/51y09td4(v=vs.71).aspx#vclrfnew_newmodifier). E.g.

```
public new DbDataReader ExecuteReader()
```

This has the usual drawbacks, as described in the [MSDN reference article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/51y09td4(v=vs.71).aspx#vclrfnew_newmodifier).